# ASP.NET MVC C# Razor Minification

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Does anybody have any idea about how to output minified HTML and JavaScript from the Razor engine while keeping custom coding styles?

For example: i want the following code:

```
<div
    @if (Model.Name != string.Empty)
        @:id="@Model.Name"
>
</div>
```

To be outputted as `<div id="DivId"></div>` .

Comment: Another solution would be to store the Html markup as string in a json property, and remove extra html markup from that json property using regex

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Look at http://arranmaclean.wordpress.com/2010/08/10/minify-html-with-net-mvc-actionfilter/.
there is an example for creating custom action filter witch clear html from WhiteSpaces

**Update**: The source code quoted from above.

The stream class for removing "blanks"

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace RemoveWhiteSpace.ActionFilters
{
    public class WhiteSpaceFilter : Stream
    {

        private Stream _shrink;
        private Func<string, string> _filter;

        public WhiteSpaceFilter(Stream shrink, Func<string, string> filter)
        {
            _shrink = shrink;
            _filter = filter;
        }


        public override bool CanRead { get { return true; } }
        public override bool CanSeek { get { return true; } }
        public override bool CanWrite { get { return true; } }
        public override void Flush() { _shrink.Flush(); }
        public override long Length { get { return 0; } }
        public override long Position { get; set; }
        public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            return _shrink.Read(buffer, offset, count);
        }
        public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
        {
            return _shrink.Seek(offset, origin);
        }
        public override void SetLength(long value)
        {
            _shrink.SetLength(value);
        }
        public override void Close()
        {
            _shrink.Close();
        }

        public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            // capture the data and convert to string 
            byte[] data = new byte[count];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, offset, data, 0, count);
            string s = Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);

            // filter the string
            s = _filter(s);

            // write the data to stream 
            byte[] outdata = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s);
            _shrink.Write(outdata, 0, outdata.GetLength(0));
        }
    }
}
```

The `ActionFilter` class:

```
public class WhitespaceFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {

        var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

        response.Filter = new WhiteSpaceFilter(response.Filter, s =>
                {
                    s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\s+", " ");
                    s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\s*\n\s*", "\n");
                    s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\s*\>\s*\<\s*", "><");
                    s = Regex.Replace(s, @"<!--(.*?)-->", "");   //Remove comments

                    // single-line doctype must be preserved 
                    var firstEndBracketPosition = s.IndexOf(">");
                    if (firstEndBracketPosition >= 0)
                    {
                        s = s.Remove(firstEndBracketPosition, 1);
                        s = s.Insert(firstEndBracketPosition, ">");
                    }
                    return s;
                });

        }

}
```

And in the end the usage of above:

```
[HandleError]
[WhitespaceFilter]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
     ...
}
```

Comment: You should edit your answer to include an example incase the link should ever go dead.

Comment: @ashley-medway coping this whole example will be difficult. Because I will have to copy text plus images. Don't you think?

Comment: It might be difficult but its the right thing to do otherwise this post could become useless down the line.

Comment: The Regex may not work because streams work in chunks at a time. If the string ends on a chunk boundary, it will not `Replace`. To get around this, I just put everything into a StringBuilder and processed everything in `Close`.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you looking for [Meleze.Web](http://nuget.org/packages/Meleze.Web)

> Meleze.Web is a toolbox to optimize ASP.NET MVC 3.0 and MVC 4.0 applications.
>   It provides HTML, JS and CSS minification of Razor views and caching of the returned pages.

**Darin Dimitrov** write about it here: [ASP.Net MVC Razor Views - Minifying HTML at build time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623348/asp-net-mvc-razor-views-minifying-html-at-build-time)

But I think enabling `gzip` is better solution, you could read about it here: [Minify HTML output from an ASP.Net MVC Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104513/minify-html-output-from-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: Meleze.web does not minify partial views.

Comment: @webdeveloper I always see this reply "_enabling gzip is better solution_" in these questions. Wouldn't be better to minify _and_ gzip at the same time? and even throw in client side caching for js & css etc?

Comment: @K-SaMa Minification for views in simple it's removing spaces, for jquery it is removing spaces and changing function, variables name and etc. It's simple for js libs, because it is static. And it's performance problem for big dynamic pages, although gzip also affects performance. For client minify+gzip is better, but you should check CPU usage, IIS stores gziped static files in special folder, but all dynamic files gziped on the fly.

Comment: I built a very tiny and trivial Razor output minifier for ASP.NET MVC 5 that operates in compile-time and is very easy to set up and understand, check it out if you're interested: https://github.com/tompazourek/RazorHtmlMinifier.Mvc5 As stated in the answer, it's best to use in combination with gzip, you can still get smaller responses if you minify and then gzip (see [Mads Kristensen's article on this](https://madskristensen.net/blog/effects-of-gzipping-vs-minifying-html-files/))

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that there is any way to achieve that. To avoid the tag soup I usually prefer writing custom helpers:

```
@using(Html.MyDiv(Model.Name))
{
    ... put the contents of the div here
}
```

and here's how the custom helper might look like:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    private class Div : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly ViewContext context;
        private bool disposed;

        public Div(ViewContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this.disposed)
            {
                this.disposed = true;
                context.Writer.Write("</div>");
            }
        }
    }

    public static IDisposable MyDiv(this HtmlHelper html, string id)
    {
        var div = new TagBuilder("div");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
            div.GenerateId(id);
        }
        html.ViewContext.Writer.Write(div.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));
        return new Div(html.ViewContext);            
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could also do a tag soup:

```
<div@Html.Raw(Model.Name != string.Empty ? string.Format(" id=\"{0}\"", Html.AttributeEncode(Model.Name)) : string.Empty)>
</div>
```

Comment: Custom helpers would've been my advice :)

Answer (score 1):

For anybody interested in this, I built a simple HTML minification library that can be used with MVC 5:

https://github.com/tompazourek/RazorHtmlMinifier.Mvc5

It operates in compile-time instead of runtime, so it doesn't add any performance overhead. The minification is very simple (just replaces lots of spaces with one space).

Even with GZIP enabled on top of the minified HTML, it can [still reduce the payload size](https://madskristensen.net/blog/effects-of-gzipping-vs-minifying-html-files/).